# How to construct a query after reading fields from a file?

Tags: kettle

I am pretty new to kettle. I am reading few fields from a csv file like name, address, city, salary. I want to insert this data into a table as "sum of salaries for each state"
So after reading from csv file using file input step. After that how can I construct a sql in javascript step so that i get sum of salaries grouped by state

Thanks
Sidharth

Comment: Please provide some code.. what do you have so far? What is your exact problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on doing the computation inside of kettle, below may work for you.

1) After input step. 
2) Add a Sort rows step (located under the Transform folder)
2.a) Sort by the field you wish to sum over. You noted state but I did not see state in your list of fields. Assuming it's available you would sort by state.
3) Add a Group by step (located under Statistics folder).
3.a) Group field 1 = State
3.b) Aggregates 
3.b.1) Name = SumByState
3.b.2) Subject = Salary
3.b.3) Type = Sum
4) Connect to your desired output.

Alternatively, you could straight load the data into a SQL database by attaching a "Table output" step after you input step. Then run below to create the summation.

```
SELECT
    State
    , SUM(Salary)
FROM TABLELOADEDWITHDATA
GROUP BY State;
```